# Problem connecting to SQL Server (Express)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Using VB.NET and Visual Studio 2008. With the code below I get

> Cannot find Table 0

```
Public ConnString As String = "Data Source=NOD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbaseManipulation;Integrated Security=True"

    Public Function ExecuteSQLStatement(ByVal SQLString As String, ByVal myDataGrid As DataGridView)
        Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
        sqlconn.Open()
        Try
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLString, sqlconn)
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
            myDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        sqlDataAdapter.Dispose()
        myDataSet.Dispose()
        sqlconn.Dispose()
        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: If you get an error, it would help if you told us the error.  Your function always returns true, which probably is misleading.  Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Your function does NOT allow for that.

Comment: I am currently making a system, and whenever i insert a new record to "Courses", i always get the error "Cannot find table 0" but it just adds to the sql server database

Comment: What's the contents of your `SQLString` ?? That's the SQL statement that gets executed to read the data

Comment: I see no errors in my save button code

Comment: ExecuteSQLStatement("INSERT INTO Courses VALUES ('" & txtCourse.Text & "')", dgv)

Comment: it the problem on the connection to sql server? im clueless and i'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: Use a ExecuteNonQuery instead.  Avoid the DataAdapter.  You aren't using parameters.  That's a big no no.

Comment: how will i do it then? just replace dataadapter with executenonquery?

Comment: i'll just study that on my own, been searching for ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: `Using cmd As New SqlCommand(...) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery End Using`  Don't ignore the parameters comment.  It's really important.

Answer (score 0):

Update, thanks to Lars for the clarification that you're performing an INSERT. That is not clear in your request for help.

The code below can serve as a clean example, but please do not accept this as an answer.

```
Public Function ExecuteSQLStatement(ByVal SQLString As String, ByVal myDataGrid As DataGridView)

    Dim result As Boolean = True
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("dsData")

    Try

        Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnString)

            cnn.Open()

            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLString, cnn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            sda.Fill(myDataSet)

        End Using

        myDataGrid.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception

        result = False
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: If you read the comments, the OP is performing an Insert query.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you fixed.  You gave no explanation.  Command objects are Text by default.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful to know, @LarsTech. Well, at least the code is cleaner, and I'm never a fan of defaults, hence the explicit declaration.

Comment: Also fixed the Function returning True regardless of any exception thrown.

Comment: @CriticalError The datagrid/dataset/dataadapter code needs to be removed. The query should be performed with [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) (q.v.).

Comment: That's correct, @AndrewMorton. The fact that an INSERT was being performed was not clear before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line

```
Public ConnString As String = "Data Source=NOD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbaseManipulation;Integrated Security=True"
'A Function must be declared with a DataType
Public Function InsertCourse() As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    'Using blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed
    'even if there is an error
    Using sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString)
        'List the column names in the Insert that match the Values clause
        'I guessed at the field name CourseName. Correct with the actual name
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Courses (CourseName) VALUES (@CourseName)", sqlconn)
            'Use Parameters - avoid SQL Injection and syntax errors
            'I guessed at the datatype. Check your database and adjust.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CourseName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCourse.Text
            'Open the connection at the last minute, End Using will close and dispose it.
            sqlconn.Open()
            RetVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
    End Using

    If RetVal = 1 Then
        Return True
        'Try to keep your Subs and Function to a single responsibility
        UpdateGrid()
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
Private Sub UpdateGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Courses:", sqlconn)
            'The load method fills the data table and closes the reader
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```